# Maven: unpack zip artifact to a SPECIFIC folder name

Tags: tomcat, maven, unpack, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to download tomcat zip artifact and unpack it int a folder named tomcat.
What i get is tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.19/
How can I get rid of the annoying intermediate directory?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>unpack-tomcat</id>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.19-win64</version>
                    <type>zip</type>
                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                    <outputDirectory>tomcat</outputDirectory>
                    <excludes>webapps/**</excludes>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>                            
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe there is more "mavenish" way for achieving my proposal :) yet using maven ant plugin could be a workaround for your situation :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <move file   = "tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.19/*"
                                      tofile = "tomcat" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <delete dir = "tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.19"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

**maven unpack with flat path**

http://pulkitsinghal.blogspot.com/2011/04/jetspeed-finally-unpack-plugin-with.html:

> There is absolutely no way (known to me as of this blog post writing)
> to get this maven plugin to spit out a flat structure.
>
> So a good alternative is to use the [jetspeed-unpack-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=jetspeed-unpack-maven-plugin) which
> allows the users to specify `<flat>true</flat>` as part of the
> [configuration](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/buildguide/jetspeed-unpack-plugin.html) in order to obtain the desired file without the burden
> of having the relative path from the root of the artifact included as
> well.

Docs state that this plugin is also able to unzip arbitrary relative path inside zipped maven artifact to specific destination folder.

Comment: The plugin might not work in Maven 3.6 as reported in issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JS2-1366.

Answer (score -2):

Use [unpack-depencencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) goal and set useSubDirectoryPerArtifact to false.

Comment: I dont manage it to work. Now it just brings me all dependencies I got and doesnt filter only tomcat.

Comment: Under the configuration section of your plugin declaration in your pom add <includeArtifactIds>tomcat<includeArtifactIds>

Comment: I posted the entire pom plugin code. It still doesnt work for me. Just create nested dir

Comment: This absolutely does not work, and useSubDirectoryPerArtifact is set to false by default anyway as per the manual.

Comment: @marcv81 The default value doesn't mean much when the OP could have set it to something other than the default. And the OP didn't post his POM until after I posted my answer. Please think about treading a little more gently.

Comment: @BenjaminLinus: Apologies for the brutality of my previous comment. I definitely need to chill a little.